# Как объединить неопределённое число запросов в RxJava 2?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, rxjava

Необходимо строки из ArrayList отправлять в api, который возвращает Single. Все Single надо объединить в обработать в одном Consumer.

Основная проблема в том, что размер ArrayList не нормирован, он может быть любым. **Как сделать объединение неопределенного количества Single в Rxjava?**

Comment: Вы каждый раз отправляете по одной строчке из списка?

Comment: Да, по одной строчке. Данные отправляются с сервис TTS Яндекса, там максимальная длина текста- 5000 символов

Comment: должен быть запрос где можно отправлять сразу список, не верю что такого нет

Comment: Почитайте, я не нашел https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/tts/request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В rxjava (и первой и второй) для объединения потоков observable часто используют merge и concat, в зависимости от того нужны данные последовательно или нет.

Сделал класс Api для теста:

```
public class Api {
    public Single<String> send(String s) {

        return Single.defer(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Single.just(s);
        });
    }
}
```

Дальше пробуй так:

**Rxjava2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
    Api api = new Api();

    List<Single<String>> collect = list.stream().map(api::send).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Flowable<String> concat = Single.concat(collect);
    concat.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

**Rxjava1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Api api = new Api();

    List<Observable<String>> collect = list.stream()
        .map(api::send)
        .map(Single::toObservable)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Observable<String> concated = Observable.concat(collect);
    concated.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

---

EDIT

Без stream api

**Rxjava2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> requests = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Api api = new Api();

    List<Single<String>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String request : requests) {
        responses.add(api.send(request));
    }

    Flowable<String> concatResponses = Single.concat(responses);
    concatResponses.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

**Rxjava1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> requests = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d");
    Api api = new Api();

    List<Observable<String>> responses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String request : requests) {
        responses.add(api.send(request).toObservable());
    }

    Observable<String> concatResponses = Observable.concat(responses);
    concatResponses.subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Есть решение для api < 24? (stream api поддерживается только с minSdk >=24)

Comment: Стримы же не очень сложно развернуть. Обновил.